# Error when using biblatex together with nature-style file

Tags: biblatex

I recently decided to use biblatex the first time for a project, so please make your explanations understandable for a complete biblatex beginnner.

I like the citation style of the http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature package, but when I run it with biblatex, I get this error:

Bibliography macro 'related' undefined

My (probably very unsophisticated) solution to this problem was to comment out all `\usebibmacro{related}%` instances in the `nature.bbx` file, which - surprisingly - is working up till now, but it still left me wondering:

- What is this macro good for?
- Will I run into any problems once I cite more than 3 references?

If it is of any relevance, I use biblatex 1.7 because that is the latest version in the repositories for ubuntu. And I'm using bibtex as a backend.

Comment: The style file needs a more up-to-date version of `biblatex`. The fact that Ubuntu runs (sometimes) years behind the current TeX Live is well known: is installing a 'stand alone' TeX system an option?

Comment: Well, firstly `biblatex 1.7` is quite an old and outdated version (the current is 2.8a). If you do not use any of the advanced `related` features `biblatex` provides (there is no `related` in your `.bib` file; see more in §3.4 *Related Entries* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)), you're probably fine commenting out `\usebibmacro{related}`. Even better would of course be an update to a new TeXLive.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I won't need the functionality of `related`, so I'll just ignore this until I finished my thesis, and then I'll think about an update. Right now I don't really want to do anything to my installation that might screw anything up, because I wouldn't have time to fix it. Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated package (`biblatex` version 1.7).